# Free product not abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-product

If $(G_i)$, $i \in I$ with $|I| > 1$ and $|G_i| > 1$ is the free product $G$ of $(G_i)$,$i \in I$ always not-commutative? The free product of a family of groups $(G_i)$, $i \in I$ is defined
by a tuple $(G, (\phi_i)_{i \in I})$ where $G$ is a group and $\phi_i : G_i \rightarrow G$ are homomorphisms, with the following property:
For every tuple $(U, (g_i)_{i \in I})$ where $U$ is a group and $g_i : G_i \to U$ are homomorphisms, there exists a unique homomorphism $f : G \to U$ with $g_i = f \circ \phi_i$ for all $i \in I$.
I thought that since $|G_i| > 1$ and $|I| > 1$ I can choose
$a_i \in G_i$ and $a_j \in G_j$ with $i \neq j$, $a_i \neq e_i $ with $a_j \neq e_j$. I wanted to show this by contraposition assuming $\phi_i(a_i) \phi_j(a_j) = \phi_j(a_j) \phi_i(a_i)$ for all $i \neq j$ and wanted to show that $a_i = e_i$ or $a_j = e_j$ but I can't really come to this conclusion since all Groups $G_i$ can be commutative and the only think that comes in my mind is that $G$ is generated by
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{i \in I}{\phi_i(G_i)}
\end{equation}
which doesn't really help.
I would be thankful for every hint I can get.

Comment: It seems you are familiar with the universal property of free products. Are you familiar with any construction (i.e., not by the universal property) of a free product of groups?

Comment: I think of it as the free group is generated from (reduced) words  $\phi_j(a_j) \ldots \phi_i(a_i)$ where $a_j \in G_j$ for $j \in I$.

Comment: There is an additional restriction. If two consecutive letters are from the same $G_i$ (we can assume the groups are disjoint), then we reduce the word by removing both letters and substituting their product in $G_i$ if it’s not identity.

Comment: So $\phi_i(a)\phi_i(b) = \phi_i(ab) \sim \phi_i(c)$ with $a,b,c \in G_i$ for all $i \in I$. So the group $G$ is under the assumption that $G$ is commutative generated by words $\phi_i(a_i)\ldots \phi_j(a_j)$ where $a_i \neq e_i$ for $i \in I$ and the empty word $e$.

Comment: No, there is not any commutativity assumption, neither in the definition of free products using the universal property, nor in constructions of free products.

Comment: I meant for the proof through contraposition I assumed that $G$ is commutative and I wanted to show that this leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One construction of a free product of groups is that it is the set of all words

$$
\phi_i(a_i) \cdots \phi_j(a_j)
$$

where

- Every pair of consecutive letters are from different $G_i$ and not identity,
- Each $\phi_i$ is an embedding of $G_i$, and
- The pairwise images of $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ intersect only at the empty word when $i \neq j$.

These words are considered *reduced*, and the operation is concatenation followed by reduction until the word satisfies the first condition.

If $a$ and $b$ are two nonidentity elements from $G_i$ and $G_j$ where $i \neq j,$ then $\phi_i(a) \phi_j(b) \phi_i(a)^{-1} \phi_j(b)^{-1}$ is a reduced word (it satisfies the first condition), but it is not the empty word.

Thus,

$$
\phi_i(a) \phi_j(b) \neq \phi_j(b) \phi_i(a),
$$

and the free product is not abelian. Of course, this depends on the fact that there are at least two nontrivial groups which are factors in the free product.

Answer (score 6):

An argument directly from the universal property:

Let $A$ be an "almost-disjoint union" of the $G_i$s, sharing a single identity element for all of them:
$$ A = \{0\} ~\cup~ \{ (i,x) \mid i\in I, x\in G_i, x\ne 0_{G_i}\} $$

Let $U$ be the group of permutations of $A$. Each $G_i$ acts on itself by left multiplication, which transfers in the natural way to an action on $A$ (namely, one that always fixes the elements that come from the other groups). This can be represented as homomorphisms $\phi_i: G_i \to U$.

Now, whenever we have *nontrivial* $x\in G_i$ and $y\in G_j$ with $i\ne j$, the two permutations $\phi_i(x)$ and $\phi_j(y)$ do not commute: $\phi_i(x)\phi_j(y)(0) = (j,y)$ whereas $\phi_j(y)\phi_i(x)(0) = (i,x)$.

Therefore when we apply the universal property to our $\phi_i$s, we get an $f$ with
$$ f(g_i(x)g_j(y)) = \phi_i(x)\phi_j(y) \ne \phi_j(y)\phi_i(x) = f(g_j(y)g_i(x)) $$
so $g_i(x)g_j(y)$ and $g_j(y)g_i(x)$ must be different elements of the free product.